# How to get BaseAdapter getTag id for each index in Android?

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-viewholder

I am trying to write a BaseAdapter code where i want to get ViewHolder Tag id on each onClickListener , but in each index i am not getting the ViewHolder tag id , it is always giving the first ViewHolder tag id. If there will be 10 items then , if i click on 3rd item then also in the Toast message i am getting the Id from the first one. But in the TextView the id is displaying correctly.

**MyCode :**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Activity activity;
Context context;
ArrayList<String> dataList;

public MyAdapter(Activity activity, Context context,ArrayList<String> dataList) 
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return dataList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView data_txt

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(convertView==null){

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.data_layout, parent,false);    
        holder.data_txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.data_txt.setText(""+holder);     

    holder.data_txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(context, ""+holder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    });

    return convertView; 
} }
```

So , my problem is how can i get the particular holder id in the Toast message. Please let me know , suggest me some good solution.

Comment: what you mean by *how can i get the particular holder id in the Toast message*?

Comment: yes i mean the same ..

Answer (score 0):

Add this field to your ViewHolder:

```
 public class ViewHolder {
   TextView data_txt
   int position;
 }
```

Change the code inside getView():

```
    if(convertView==null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.data_layout, parent,false);
        holder.data_txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data);
        holder.position = position;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = ((ViewHolder)(v.getTag)).position;
                Toast.makeText(context, Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.data_txt.setText(""+ Integer.toString(position));
    holder.position = position;
```

Comment: No i am getting NullPointerException on int position = ((ViewHolder)(v.getTag)).position;

Comment: I didn't notice you put the listener on the TextView. change it to the converView instead.

Comment: so you mean listener to convertView... how

Comment: but i am always getting 0 as id value